# Getting started with Pynetbox

Tags: python, api, netbox

So I'm trying to get started with the Netbox API. However, so far i have been unsuccessful to even recreate simple tutorials.
I've created the API user and token.

Here is the basic object creation:

```
nb = pynetbox.api(url="<myurl>", token="<mytoken>")
nb.http_session.verify = False
```

Only thing I got to work is *print(nb.version)*.
If I try

```
all_prefixes = nb.ipam.prefixes.all()
print(all_prefixes)
```

The output is just nothing.
If I try

```
x = nb.dcim.devices.get(1)
print(x)
```

I get Error 403 - Forbidden ('You do not have permission to perform this action.')
Can anyone help me out here? Why is it so hard to make simple requests?

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant certain permissions to the user who makes the requests to be able to get devices, prefixes, etc.
Go to https://your.netbox.instance/admin/auth/user/, select the user whose token is used for requests and grant certain permissions:

[image: NetBox user permissions]

Alternatively, you can make the user superuser so that you don't have to explicitly list the required permissions:

[image: NetBox superuser checbox]